# Xamarin Forms creating a Folder in Local

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Creating folder by following code

```
        var documents=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
        var directoryname = Path.Combine(documents, "XX");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryname);
```

but the folder does not exists in the specific path..May i know whats the reason.

regards..

Answer (score 0):

From [Xamarin Official Site](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Environment+SpecialFolder/):

> Not all directories in this enumeration will be available on all
>   platforms for all users. When running on the Windows operating system,
>   the operating system determines the paths to these directories.

Enumeration means `Environment.SpecialFolder`.

You need to implement a [DependencyService](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/34498/environment-getfolderpath-not-exists-cross-plataform) and need to call `System.Environment.GetFolderPath` from within the platform-specific implementation.

Check [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/34498/environment-getfolderpath-not-exists-cross-plataform) sample.

As per my knowledge, it (your code) will not work in `Xamarin.Form` PCL project. 
You can do another thing is, In your Android and iOS Project you can put this code to get the platform specific path:

```
using Xamarin Forms;

//Get current Path.
Config.PathApp = System.Environment.GetFolderPath (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

Comment: What is the error? System is common name space. Check for Capital letter in system. Please share what is error?

Answer (score 0):

if you need the main picture folder on the android then your code should look like this

`string AndroidDcimFolder = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim).AbsolutePath;`

Comment: `Environment.GetExternalPublicDirectory(string?)` is now **Obsolete**, is there another way of doing this?